# Wrong splash screen for iPhone 6 and 6+ in Adobe AIR iOS application

Tags: ios, iphone, actionscript-3, air, adobe

I have a problem with my iPhone application developed in Flash and compiled with Adobe AIR sdk 15 and 16. My application is in portrait mode and I have following images for the Default splash screen of all iPhone screens

Default@2x.png [ 640x960 ] - iPhone 4

Default-568h@2x.png [ 640x1136 ]  - iphone5

Default-375w-667h@2x.png [ 750x1334 ] - iphone6

Default-414w-736h@3x.png [ 1242x2208 ] - iphone6+

I am compiling with latest air sdk 16 with following command

AdobeAIRSDK16\bin\adt  -package -target ipa-test-interpreter -provisioning-profile "Universal.mobileprovision" -storetype pkcs12 -keystore "distribution.p12" -storepass password application.ipa application.xml main.swf icons/ assets/ -extdir lib/ Default@2x.png Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png Default-568h@2x.png Default-375w-667h@2x.png Default-414w-736h@3x.png

When I run it on iphone6, app looks fine but its using iPhone5 splash screen ie Default-568h@2x.png. If I take screenshot of the app, those are also in 640x1136 size.

I already lost 10 days in googling and trying several options, even tried 64 bit on mac without any luck. Can someone let me know if its a known issue or any workaround available.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This thread of discussions might help

https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1579018